# How can I perform only one swap on button press?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, break, bubble-sort

```
async bubbleSort(values, size) {
    sort_button = true;
    for(var i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) { 
        for(var j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++) { 
            if(values[j] >= values[j + 1]) {
                states[j] = 1; // << Highlight comparisons 
                states[j + 1] = 1; 
                if (step_button == true) {
                    // TODO: Swap only two elements
                } else if (step_button != true) {
                    await this.swap(values, j, j + 1);
                }
            } 
            states[j] = 2; 
        } 
        states[j] = 0; // << Sorted Order 
    } 
    sort_button = false; 
    return values; 
}
```

I am trying to add a step feature for the following algorithm. When the step button is pressed I want one swap to be performed and the code following it to be executed. I have tried using a break and continue but this did not give me the result I was looking for. How can I simply swap two elements in the data set each time the button is pressed?

Comment: You need to monitor change in the state of the button. If the current state is "on" and the previous state is "off", that's exactly one button press. If the current state is "on" and the previous state is "on" too, that's not a button press, that's a button hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would copy the array and work on the copied version in the background and store a list of the swaps.

and each time the button got presses I just get the top element for the list and swap the indices.

Example: this 0-based array
3 1 2
the list of swaps will be
0 1
1 2

So
at the first button press, I would swap a[0] and a[1]
at the second button press, I would swap a[1] and a[2]